# MATLAB's $\tt bandpower$ function - How does it work?

Tags: matlab, fft, filters

So the function `bandpower(x,fx,freqrange)` calculates the average power within the selected frequency range.  So it basically takes a part of the periodogram, but what is the filter with which this bandwidth is selected, is it simply a rectangle or a Gaussian curve? And is there a way to change it?

[The documentation](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bandpower.html) doesnt explain it at all.

Comment: I agree, it seems underdefined in the mathworks docs. If you care about this, you might simply *not* want to use that function, and write your own (considering that isn't really complicated mathematically for you, since you already seem to understand the implications of using different bandwidth windows here).

Comment: my best guess, however, is simply a rectangle that only includes full periodogram bins; you could try that out by writing test cases where you fabricate signals that are just on, below or above the edge of the bands you analyze with `bandpower`; but designing and writing these tests is much more work than writing your own version of `bandpower`, to be completely honest :)

Comment: (which doesn't mean you shouldn't write tests for your own matlab code – when I was still doing matlab, this proved to be essential – but you'd put less thought into them)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation does sort of explain it, although it is a bit difficult to work out. So let's look at the source code as well:

```
>> edit bandpower
```

---

**Summary of bandpower**

The function `bandpower()` can be performed on a time-series or a given power spectral density (PSD) estimate.

To compute from a given time-series, the syntax are:

```
p = bandpower(x)
p = bandpower(x,fs,freqrange) % <- the one you asked about
```

To compute from a given PSD, the syntax are:

```
p = bandpower(pxx,f,'psd')
p = bandpower(pxx,f,freqrange,'psd')
```

---

**bandpower with PSD**

If you specify and give a PSD to `bandpower()` then you can use whatever window (or filter, as you say) you desire before hand. For instance,

```
n = size(x,1); % or some other window/nfft size
[Pxx, F] = periodogram(x, hamming(n), n, fs);
pwr = bandpower(Pxx, F, freqrange);
```

uses a hamming window the same size as the given FFT length (`nfft`).
`bandpower()` won't apply any other window to `Pxx` from then on.

---

**bandpower with Time-Series**

When `bandpower()` is given a time-series it is hard coded to use a hamming window (like above).
You can check this in the source code...

> ```
>  ...
>  n = size(x,1);
>  if isreal(x)
>      [Pxx, F] = periodogram(x, hamming(n), n, fs);
>  else
>      [Pxx, F] = periodogram(x, hamming(n), n, fs, 'centered');
>  end
>  % Return the bandpower
>  pwr = psdbandpower(Pxx, F, freqrange);
>  ...
> ```